# Error when using createmodel function for Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ecr, amazon-sagemaker-studio

Recently encountered this weird error with a custom image that I build. There is no issue for training and processing job. Just on when I wanted to createmodel.

ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateModel operation: Unsupported manifest media type application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json for image {image link}. Ensure that valid manifest media type is used for specified image.

Hope that somebody can provide some insight to  this problem.

Comment: My builds are done in the backend using podman hence I suspect that may be the reason

Comment: managed to solve it in the end by specifying --format. but I am still curious since I never needed to consider this previously until I reached the create-model

Comment: Can you upload some code so we can reproduce the error? I didn't understand if you solved it somehow. Please update the post with all useful information.

Comment: sorry....forgot to update the post.

Essentially, I ended up resolving it by, when building the image, to specifically indicate the --format (for podman) to docker.

Somehow, the issue is really on the OCI format somehow having some issues with createmodel, which is the default build mode for podman......I will add more details when I have time

Comment: @terrygryffindor what did you end up passing to `--format` to make it work?

Comment: --format docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SageMaker's CreateModel operation predominantly supports Docker V2 manifest media type, specifically “application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json”. Although ECR does support other manifest types, such as the Open Container Initiative (OCI) Specifications (v1.0 and up), SageMaker currently does not for the CreateModel operation.

While ECR does support a wide range of manifest formats, including the OCI, it maintains the integrity of the original image format to cater to the varied needs of different AWS services and general container workloads. Automatically translating between formats might lead to compatibility issues or unintended behaviors in some contexts. SageMaker's specific requirements stem from its internal architecture and integration points, which currently lean towards Docker V2 manifest format for the CreateModel operation.

Next Steps:

To address the error you've faced, I recommend specifying the `--format` option to `docker` when building your image, as described in this. This ensures the image is in a format that SageMaker's CreateModel operation supports.

podman --format docker build.